# Cancel installation is shown after installing my module in Odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-15

I have created a custom module which I am trying to install but it shows me cancel installation button after I try to install it.

This issue is not seen in any other custom modules or other modules. But installation is not working for my module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Cancel Installation" button could be visible on these situations.

1. Another module is being installed.
2. Whenever the server restarts.

According to your query i guess that the cause of your issue might be 'Circular Dependency'.

Please re-check your `'depends' : []` inside `__manifest__.py`